# Passing Session Variable from PHP to JS

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am currently using some jQuery that gets the content within a td cell.  I am then passing that content via a variable to another file.  I'm trying to figure out the best way to grab a session variable as well and seem to have hit a rut.  Below is some brief pseudo code along with my JS/jQuery.

EDIT/UPDATE

Correction to post below as well.  Here my ManageUsers.inc.php

```
<?php
// Load 404 page if file is accessed directly
if(!defined('INCLUDE_CHECK')) die(header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found"));

// Load 404 page if the page is accessed by Users or QA Agents
if($_SESSION['role_id']<2 or $_SESSION['role_id']==5) die(header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found"));

?>
<script src="/resources/js/getBusinessUnit.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../resources/js/User.js"></script>

<div id="main">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Manage Users</h1>
    <h2>This page allows you to add and update the authorized Users</h2>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; text-align:center;">
    <span id="user">
    <form name="insertUser" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP']);?>" method="post">
      <div style="margin-top:0px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; text-align:center;">
        <fieldset>
          <legend class="legend1"><h2>&nbsp User Info &nbsp</h2></legend>
          <div style="padding-top: 5px;">
            <input type="text" name="uname" class="textinput1" id="uname" value="" style="width:200px;" maxlength="200" tabindex="2" placeholder="User Name" /><br />
            <input type="text" name="fname" class="textinput1" id="fname" value="" style="width:200px;" maxlength="100" tabindex="3" placeholder="First Name" /><br />
            <input type="text" name="lname" class="textinput1" id="lname" value="" style="width:200px;" maxlength="100" tabindex="4" placeholder="Last Name" /><br />
            <div style="float:left"><input type="checkbox" name="status" id="status" value="YES"/>Enabled </div>
          </div>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
          <legend class="legend1"><h2>&nbsp Company Info &nbsp</h2></legend>
          <div style="padding-top: 5px;">
            <div class="input-field">
              <?php require $adm_pg.'selectRole'.$ext; ?>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="input-field">
              <?php require $adm_pg.'selectBusinessUnit'.$ext; ?>
            </div>
              <span id="DeptContainer"></span>
          </div>
        </fieldset>
      </div>

      <?php require $adm_pg.'adminButtons'.$ext; ?>
    </form>
    </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <?php require $adm_pg.'displayUsers.inc.php'; ?>
  </div>

</div>
<?php
require 'db/ManageUsers.db.php';
require 'db/logAction.db.php';
?>
```

Here is my User.js file

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
    $('.user').on('click', function() {
        var id = $(this).html();
    $.get("/includes/adminPages/Update_User.inc.php?selection_id=" + id, function(data) {
        $('#user').html(data);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Did you try just sticking <?php echo $_SESSION['bus_id'];?> in the middle of your Javascript code? (Random guess.)

Comment: @Ariane I attempted to do that first, and then testing it with an alert, but the alert wasn't popping up.  I wasn't sure if another issue existed as a result of that.

Comment: How are you passing the session back to JS now? Via the get? Also, I hope your `<td>...</td>` is within a `<table>..</table>` otherwise it is invalid.

Comment: @putvande The td is within a table.  As stated above, I just jotted down the simple pseudo code.  I'm actually passing two variables.  The first one is the content within the td.  The second is the session variable.  I'm trying to figure out a way to get the session variable so that I can send it to Update_User.inc.php

Comment: Every day somebody posts *"how to access PHP variable in JS"* or vice-versa. C'mon guys, let's try a simple search!!! -1

Comment: @CBC_NS Did you try putting an `echo` as above at a random place in your page, outside the JS? If the expected value doesn't show up, then it's simply not accessible to begin with, and you need to rework your PHP. If it does, and it's inserting PHP inside Javascript that poses a problem, then you could try to simply `echo` your value inside a hidden input and then get its value with JS. Yes, it's basically running away from the problem, but there's always that, if you can't figure out why the data transfer between PHP and JS isn't working and this isn't important enough for you to dig deep.

Comment: I basically wound up putting the value inside a hidden div.  Thank you for the suggestion.  My solution can be found below.

Answer (score 2):

Well there are two options here.

1. The PHP file could send the session variable back as part of the `data` that is returned in the `$.get` call.
2. If the session value doesn't change during the page's execution, then you could simply do as other's have suggested, by doing `echo $_SESSION['bus_id'];`

If you're having trouble getting #2 to work, here is what you do. Reduce your HTML file to this (I'll leave out the header stuff, which I assume is correct in your file):

```
<div>
<?php
    print_r($_SESSION);
?>
</div>
```

That will give you all the session values. This way you can see if the value you want is there. If it is, then this will work fine:

```
<script>
var myvar = "<?php echo $_SESSION['bus_id']; ?>";
</script>
```

With problems like this, the most important thing is to simplify them. Remove EVERYTHING that is not needed from the page, and add to the code in small steps, so you can identify where the problem is happening. *It seems like the problem you're having isn't actually the problem you think you're having :)*

**EDIT:**

Based upon the updated information, the problem is that you're expecting to run PHP code in a file that is never parsed by PHP (`User.js`). If you need access to a PHP variable in a javascript function that is defined in an external .js file, then you have to pull the variable into javascript in the main PHP file and then send it as a parameter to whatever code you're executing in the external .js file, or declare it globally and ensure it's visible to the external code. For example, using the parameter solution:

**index.php**

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="myfunctions.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var bus_id = "<?php echo $_SESSION['bus_id']; ?>";
        setup_binds(bus_id);
    });
</script>
```

**myfunctions.js**

```
function setup_binds(bus_id) {
    $(".user").on("click",function(){
        alert("bus_id is: " + bus_id);
    });
}
```

*In other words, you need to carefully think about how to design pages that include multiple files like this.*

Comment: As I mentioned down below, when I type/or paste in that line of code the way you have it and the way Sobin has it below, it is giving me a syntax error?  The session variable I want is active on the php page though.

Comment: Yeah, I had single quotes on the outside and inside. I fixed it, and that should work fine.

Comment: When I do alert(myvar) the result is <?php echo $_SESSION['bus_id']; ?>.  Will that change itself once I send that back to my php file?

Comment: Ah, okay, so this is happening in a file that is called something like `myfile.html`, right? You need to rename it to `myfile.php`.

Comment: My file name is Update_user.inc.php.  It already is a php file.  I only added HTML up top to separate the php variable from the basic html code.

Comment: Okay, well, there is no chance that my first code statement above (`print_r`) would execute PHP on the page if the second code statement (`myvar`) does not execute PHP. I'm guessing you've got this issue spread across multiple files. As I said, start fresh with a new PHP file, and just try to get the `myvar` line to work. Once you're there, make small changes towards your current code layout, and you'll discover the actual problem.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you saying that the "-JS-" code snippet you posted above is in the `update_user.inc.php` file? That would be a very bizarre design choice, as you'd either need to be creating a string that is then placed in the `<script>` section of the main PHP page, or you're executing `include_once` within the `<script>` section of the main PHP page. Either way, that's an awkward design, and it's probably a safe bet that the way you're trying to include that code is causing the problem.

Comment: No, I think you got me very wrong here.  Let me edit and update for clarification.

Comment: He could do : `<script> var myvar = <?php echo "'".$_SESSION['bus_id']."'";?></script>` the problem he his with the previous code is that the browser think the <?php?> tags are part of the string value inside myvar.

Comment: Not quite. It's not the browser that makes that decision, it's the server. When the PHP statement is returned within the string itself, that means that the server wasn't executing PHP on that section of text at all.

Comment: I'm not trying to execute php at this point.  All I'm doing is trying to get my alert to show up with the value of what should be 3.

Comment: Does he have session_start(); at the beginning of his php file ??

Comment: @CBC_NS Yes, the problem is that the file is never parsed by PHP. It's a .js file, not a .php file. This is what I was getting at when I said `"so this is happening in a file that is called something like myfile.html, right? You need to rename it to myfile.php"`. Define the variable in a script block that is created in a PHP file, and then pass it as a variable to the function you're calling in an external .js file.

Comment: @CBC_NS if you want your variable to display you will need to execute  php, because its php a variable you are trying to gives JQuery

Comment: @CBC_NS I've updated my answer to reflect what I'm suggesting.

Comment: session_start() is in my index page, and all other files are linked to it.  I have no other issues with any of my session variables.  What I'm trying to do is clear our a form which resides in a span.  The form will repopulate pending on which login name is clicked in the table at the bottom of the page.  I need to send two variables.  I am successfully obtaining the td variable which is named "id" in my js.  When I use the line var bus_id = "<?php echo $_SESSION['bus_id']; ?>"; along with alert(bus_id) the pop up box says <?php echo $_SESSION['bus_id']; ?> rather than the value.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var id = '<?php echo $_SESSION['bus_id'] ; ?>';
</script>
```

Comment: Essentially, this should be the answer.  As I mentioned above in response to Ariane, it isn't even triggering the alert.  Thoughts?

Comment: try with the single quotes for strings
and it is the way i think, it works well for me

Comment: The single quotes give a syntax error and double quotes echos/alerts out the whole line.

Comment: did it echo the result using php..??(without using js, will it working..??)

Comment: So, using your suggestion, the following happened.

    var bus_id = '<?php echo $_SESSION['bus_id'] ; ?>'; // syntax error

    var bus_id = "<?php echo $_SESSION['bus_id'] ; ?>"; // got result <?php echo $_SESSION['bus_id'] ; ?> when the alert popped up.

Comment: @CBC_NS Do you have the JS code within the HTML file (PHP code) or is it a separate file (pure JS file) which does not get parsed by PHP?

Comment: did it working outside js, i mean the <?php echo $_SESSION['bus_id'] ; ?> php code

Comment: @RaffaelLuthiger The JS is in a different source file.  I can get the td value.  That part works fine.  I'm just trying to figure out the easiest way to get the session variable.

Comment: its only a try, since the js is in different source, put the code in the php file before the js include and try accessing the variable from the js source

Answer (score 0):

What I like to do from PHP to JS is use JSON for just about everything and then view the response in a console.

This is obviously not safe and I haven't tested this code, but the idea is something like:

PHP

```
<?php
   $id = $_REQUEST['id'];  // the id sent
   ...
   echo json_encode($_SESSION);
?>
```

[AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings)

```
... on('click','delegate', function() { ...

$.ajax(url, {  // $.getJSON works well too
   dataType:'json', 
   data:{id:someid}, 
   success:function(ses){
       // you should see the whole session as a tree 
       console.debug(ses);  
       // I also like to see big trees in the "DOM" in firebug
       window.SESSION = ses;
   }});
})
```

I feel like this just opens up the overall picture of the data, and you end up making fewer callbacks because you can communicate more by passing objects. You can also do things like handle messages and not just errors.

Answer (score 0):

I went about this pretty easily.  To simplify my problem I just made a hidden div with the session variable in it.  I then set bus_id = (element.value) where element was the name of the hidden div id.

Solution...

```
<input type = "hidden" id="bus" name="bus" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['bus_id']; ?>">
```

then in my JS

```
bus_id = (bus.value);
```